# VTune Profiler giving Error: "The Data Cannot be displayed,there is no viewpoint available for data "

Tags: c++, linux, intel-vtune

I want to optimize my code which is written in c++  on linux platform.For that i am using Intel VTune Performance Analyzer Profiler .When i am identifying **Hotspots** , it successfully runs the binary executable whose path i have specified and then it gives **Error:** "**The Data Cannot be displayed,there is no viewpoint available for data "**.

Can anyone help please in sorting this error.

Comment: Which version of the product you are using?  Can you make sure you run the latest one?  Also, can you send me the result directory that doesn't open, I'll take a look?  I am a VTune developer.

Comment: @Nightingale Thanks for Reply . i am using INTEL VTUNE AMPLIFIER XE 2013 update 5 ....how can i attach a file here . Can u pls suggest ?

Comment: Can you just share the file using some file sharing service?  E.g. http://depositfiles.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have just resolved the same problem, hope it's not too late for you.

Firs of all, you should enable debug information, i.e. compile with `-g` option:

```
icpc -g -o output source.cpp
```

or

```
gcc -g -o output source.cpp
```

if you prefer GNU compiler.

Another step (non-trivial) was found [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/375990): it says that at least for Ubuntu you have to type in:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

This operation helped me and I hope it will help you and other people who face with this issue in future.